# R Shiny selectizeInput cuts selected keywords in choices list

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I have a disturbing problem with selectizeInput. Whenever I search for several key words, the words are cut or deleted completely. In the minimal example below, when I fill in "producer price", the word "Producer" is completely deleted in each choice in the list.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "id_category",
                     label = "Category (multiple answers possible)",
                     multiple = TRUE,
                     choices = c("Producer price oil",
                                 "Producer price pulp",
                                 "Producer price oat",
                                 "Import price oil")),
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Can't reproduce, everything works well for me. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot. At least my colleague can reproduce it :/

Comment: I forgot to type "producer price" in the search. Very strange bug indeed

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2957) looks similar, but there's no fix for this apparently

Comment: It seems to be [this issue](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/1149).

Comment: Do you know how to fix this highlighting issue within Shiny?

Comment: The discussion on the selectize.js GitHub page seems to suggest the problem is fixed in the latest version (v0.13.6) but it looks like Shiny is still using an older version.

Comment: I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3700).

Answer (score 1):

I see that @ismirsehregal filed an issue, as an alternative option if you don't have a long list of choices you could use
[shinyWidgets::pickerInput](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/pickerInput.html)
it works with the same args that you have for selectizeInput, with multiple selections get checkmark on the dropdown menu of choices.